# Large text file dictionary of random words for benchmarking purposes?

Tags: data-structures, text, dataset, computer-science

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a very very large dictionary of random words that could be used to test some high performance string data structures?  I'm finding some that are in the ~2MB range... however I'd like some larger if possible.  I'm guessing there has to be some large standard string dataset somewhere that could be used.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://norvig.com/big.txt

The above link was mentioned in Norvig's spell checker article - http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look through the material available at the [TREC](http://trec.nist.gov/data.html) (Text REtrieval Conference).  Some good datasets which might meet your requirements.